# Versioning hubs in SignalR

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, signalr

Are there ability to have different versions of the same hub that is chosen based on version sent by JS client ?

Surely there must be some kind of recommended best-practice for handling hub evolution (adding methods, changing parameters in existing methods, removing operations, etc) when you don't necessarily have control over client versions.

Comment: User a different hub?

Comment: @TheGeneral, knowing which version of web-app user is using I need to connect him to corresponding hub

Comment: Can you be more specific? Can you describe a sample difference in versions and the intention of how you intend to handle the difference if u1 uses the old version and u2 uses the new version?

Comment: For `SignalR`, it enables the server and client calls methods in other side with methods name. You could not define the same method in the same hub. If different user accesses different methods, you need to control the calling from client side instead of server side. The server only defines the method, which methods to call is controlled by client side. If you need different hubs, you may try to define different hubs with different urls by `app.UseSignalR(route =>{ route.MapHub<ChatHub>("/chathub"); route.MapHub<ChatHub1>("/chathub1");});`

Answer (score 0):

```
public void MyHubMethod(MyRequestModel model)
{
    if (model.Version > 1)
    {
        // If Param2 == null ==> Error!
        // Do stuff with Param2
    }
    else
    {
        // Preserve the old behavior, where Param1 was used and Param2 was optional
        // Do stuff with Param1
        if (model.Param2 != null)
        {
            // Do stuff with Param2
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Here is discussion on github - https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/5373#issuecomment-437434263 
where Andrew describes concerns about that idea